# MS Surface LTE: How can I enumerate available Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLine's?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime

I wonder if it's possible to write an UWP Phone app utilizing objects of the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls) namespace on a 2-in-1 device, like, e.g., the Microsoft Surface Go LTE, for making phone calls using the inserted SIM card.

How can I enumerate all available [phone lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phoneline) to make a call on such line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use [PhoneLineWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLineWatcher?view=winrt-19041#remarks) class to enumerate all available phone lines, for example:

```
Task<Dictionary<Guid, PhoneLine>> getPhoneLinesTask = GetPhoneLinesAsync();
……
    
private async Task<Dictionary<Guid,PhoneLine>> GetPhoneLinesAsync()
{
    PhoneCallStore store = await PhoneCallManager.RequestStoreAsync();
    var watcher = store.RequestLineWatcher();
    var phoneLines = new List<PhoneLine>();
    var lineEnumberationCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    watcher.LineAdded += async (o, args) =>
    {
        var line = await PhoneLine.FromIdAsync(args.LineId);
        phoneLines.Add(line);
    };
    watcher.Stopped += (o, args) => lineEnumberationCompletion.TrySetResult(false);
        watcher.EnumerationCompleted += (o, args) => lineEnumberationCompletion.TrySetResult(true);
    watcher.Start();
    if(!await lineEnumberationCompletion.Task)
    {
        throw new Exception("Phone Line Enumeration failed");
    }
    watcher.Stop();
    Dictionary<Guid, PhoneLine> returnedLines = new Dictionary<Guid, PhoneLine>();
    foreach(PhoneLine phoneLine in phoneLines)
    {
        if(phoneLine!=null&&phoneLine.Transport==PhoneLineTransport.Cellular)
        {
            returnedLines.Add(phoneLine.Id, phoneLine);
        }
    }

    return returnedLines;
}
```

Note, add the `phoneCall` capability before accessing all of the phone lines.
For more information about phone call, you can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/v8.0.7/archived/PhoneCall) in GitHub.